# TypeScript recursive union function type

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, union, type-theory

I'm trying to express the infinite family of types:

```js
type Q0 = number;
type Q1 = (x: number) => number;
type Q2 = (x: (x: number) => number) => number;
type Q3 = (x: (x: (x: number) => number) => number) => number;
// ...
```

as a union type.
If I define:

```js
type Q = number | ((x: Q) => number);
```

and a little helper:

```js
type IsSubtypeOf<S, T> = S extends T ? true : false;
```

I find that:

```js
type _1 = IsSubtypeOf<number, Q>; // => true
type _2 = IsSubtypeOf<(x: number) => number, Q>; // => false
```

So `(x: number) => number` isn't an inhabitant of type `Q`, defying my expectations.

I expected that `Q` is equivalent to the union of all of its "ground instances".
That is, that `Q` is the same as:

```js
type Q1
  = number
  | ((x: number) => number)
  | ((x: (x: number) => number) => number)
  | ((x: (x: (x: number) => number) => number) => number)
  // ...
```

but in that case, `(x: number) => number` *would* be a subtype of `Q1`.

What am I missing here?

### Appendix

I tried "unrolling" `Q` by adding another ground instance, and this *does* work (not suprisingly):

```js
type Q2 = number | ((x: number) => number) | ((x: Q2) => number);

type _3 = IsSubtypeOf<(x: number) => number, Q2>; // => true
```

Comment: Function types are contravariant in their inputs, so `(x: (A | B))=>void` is not the same as `((x: A)=>void) | ((x: B)=>void)`.   So if you try to treat a `(x: number)=>number` as a `Q` you get [potential runtime explosions](https://tsplay.dev/NBdPzW) and you're warned about it. Does that fully address the question (which is, as far as I can tell, "what am I missing here" and not "can I represent an infinite union of functions recursively", for which the answer is "no")? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! I took some time to think about this more, and I'm starting to grok how function variance works now. To answer your question: yes, that does fully address the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to write the infinite [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

```
type Q = number | 
    ((x: number) => number) | 
    ((x: (x: number) => number) => number) | 
    ((x: (x: (x: number) => number) => number) => number) | 
    ⋯;
```

in TypeScript. At best you can pick some reasonable maximum length of the union and write a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) to achieve it:

```
type QLen<N extends number, A extends any[] = [number]> =
    N extends A["length"] ? A[number] : QLen<N, [(x: A[0]) => number, ...A]>;

type Q = QLen<10>;
```

---

In particular, the desired infinite union is *not* equivalent to

```
type NotQ = number | ((x: NotQ) => number);
```

One cannot "push" a union into the parameter type for a function and keep things the same.  Functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types.  (See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) .) Unions turn into [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) and vice-versa.  So `NotQ` would be expanded to

```
type NotQ = number | ((x: number | ((x: NotQ) => number)) => number);
```

which is equivalent to

```
type NotQ = number | (((x: number) => number) & ((x: NotQ) => number));
```

And this does not even begin to resemble your desired infinite union.

---

For a more concrete reason why you cannot assign an `(x: number) => number` to `NotQ`, you can see what happens if it were allowed:

```
const f = (x: number) => x.toFixed(2).length;
//    ^? const f: (x: number) => number

const q: NotQ = f; // error, but imagine it weren't
```

Here we have made the bad assignment.  According to the definition of `NotQ`, if `q` isn't a `number` then it must be a `((x: NotQ) => number)`.  And in that case you would be allowed to call `q(q)`:

```
if (typeof q !== "number") {
    q(q) // no compiler error, but...  at runtime
}
```

Of course if you actually run that, you'll get the runtime error that `x.toFixed` is not a function.  Because `q` is actually `f`, which assumes that its input is a `number`, and therefore has a `toFixed()` method.  But you've passed in `q`, not a number, and thus `q(q)` explodes.  We've lied to the compiler about the type of thing `q` really is, and we've been penalized for it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIBcE8AcFNwEUAM4C84B2BXAtgEbwBOA3KBDAsgIwbgAUAHgFzb5HECUGAfO4RLkwUOIiQAmeszYyBnHun65B3PvKEVR1JAGZprRobkqF60yUXKOl8zbLBgVcQBl4WADwA5cPCaR3ABMAZw1iABpwAEFffyDQgEMsaABtAF16FItiNP50YHBC8B8-AKwQ6JSAIgAbdwBzSAALKoyAfkrsjLYkN08vSJS5KJSUNKswyIA6Gajc8icxZHpe9w8aFF5HR2dwAElggGUcAmcAeQAzD0PIgBU88EPYsorb8A7IYhxENguEmuC8AWuwA+nRMAdjqcxJcPNlIl4APaQJC8UjgERKKBfeCLaggqQQo4nc5XEz2Cbw4rI1HozH8P4A3F4xBIlH0bLgAA+jDkbKQlIpwhAu35HPs3N5hk5PIYfJpgtUXEVCmFopp4tUkrl5KVdj1ADIpWx+SrLFwFsAAMaIrDBSDgC4GNjZCZMKaQREAMQAlkx4IEGBIuFM6lhGk1hUVwAA9NrW2328AARxNGswFzpEA8AFoc1Amj7QkXwElfMRiIjiI6q6XwPVEYjAuBiPAEsFbY4fU6GM5EU7k+AAIToTBVbJVHgAbwKRWTDGTPBEXywkB9eEQJEr1bOAAlimdIu7Pb7-c2S1hkXWLjgsFa17bwMAAL7gIA)